# cannot import name 'CredentialsFileSymbolicLinkError'

Tags: python-3.x, pip, ubuntu-16.04, pydrive

I install pydrive using pip3 with `--user`. When trying to run an [example script](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/quickstart.html#authentication), I get the following error:

```
$ python3 quick.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quick.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pydrive.drive import GoogleAuth
  File "/home/fauzan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pydrive/drive.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .files import GoogleDriveFile
  File "/home/fauzan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pydrive/files.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .auth import LoadAuth
  File "/home/fauzan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pydrive/auth.py", line 15, in <module>
    from oauth2client.file import CredentialsFileSymbolicLinkError
ImportError: cannot import name 'CredentialsFileSymbolicLinkError'
```

What I tried doing was manually editing oauth2client's file.py and adding the missing exception from [the github repo](https://github.com/gsutil-mirrors/google-api-python-client/blob/master/oauth2client/file.py) (line 32). However, then I encountered an Import error, that there is no module named `oauth2client.util`. Pydrive's auth.py imports `scopes_to_string` from `oauth2client.util`. I checked the oauth2client package folder, and util.py was not present.

I then uninstalled pydrive, oauth2client and google-api-python-client using pip and pip3. Then I installed pydrive agian, this time also with `--no-cache-dir`. Again the CredentialFile... error was thrown. I don't know how to proceed further.

I don't want to spend days figuring how to go about installing packages, that time be better spend writing code. :(

What I observed that the github repo differed quite a bit from the package files on my system.

**Edit**: There seem to be two oauth2client packages [this](https://github.com/google/oauth2client) and [this](https://github.com/gsutil-mirrors/google-api-python-client/tree/master/oauth2client)

**Edit**: This is bug and is being [tracked](https://github.com/googledrive/PyDrive/issues/78)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're experiencing this issue pydrive needs to be updated to a version >= 1.3.1.
Using pip from a command prompt:

```
pip install pydrive --upgrade
```

Just submitting this as an answer so that we can mark this as solved/answered.

Comment: Thank you! I tried so many things but this is the one that worked out for me. Thumbs up!